# How to add a gap at the end of every page in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

How to add bottom gap in every crystal report.

**I can add the gap in page footer,But** report has a background water mark in page header.So if add the gap in page footer, gap will be shown as blank white space.
Any Idea ?
[image]

Comment: How about margin? Bottom Margin of the Report

Comment: @MohitShrivastava but margin will be blank white space,i want to show the water mark in the gap also

Comment: add another section and leave it empty with the amount of space you want.

Comment: @aMazing is it possible to print the section in every page footer